# How To Receive Multipart Request From Retrofit API

Tags: android, spring-rest

I am using Spring-rest at server side. here i am handling request from android app. but , i am unable to receive multipart files uploaded from android app. android app developers sending multiple files as in the form of List. for receiving that request at server side i used below code.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/multipleFilesUpload" , method=RequestMethod.POST, 
                consumes="multipart/form-data", produces="application/json")  
public ResponseEntity<?> mutipleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest req, 
                                           @RequestParam(value="files" , required = false) List<MultipartFile> files,
                                           @RequestParam("desc") String desc) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Hits::"+desc);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(files.get(i).getOriginalFilename());
    }



    return null;
}
```

But, i am getting empty List. 
Please , give a suggestion how to receive multiple files in spring - rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a `multipart/form-data` then the method parameters should be `@RequestPart` not `@RequestParam`, and you method might look like below where list of MultiPart File will come in `@RequestPart(value="files" , required = false) MultipartFile... files` and `@RequestPart("desc") String desc` will be the JSON part of the payload.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/multipleFilesUpload" , method=RequestMethod.POST, 
                consumes="multipart/form-data", produces="application/json")  
public ResponseEntity<?> mutipleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest req, 
                                           @RequestPart(value="files" , required = false) MultipartFile... files,
                                           @RequestPart("desc") String desc) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Hits::"+desc);

    List<MultipartFile> fileList = Arrays.asList(files);
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getOriginalFilename());
    }



    return null;
}
```